# How to use time and date types in one condition to express the period?

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT id,the_day,the_time FROM micro_climate 
WHERE the_day>'2015-01-01' AND the_day<'2015-02-01' 
AND the_time between '20:00:00' and '20:00:00';
```

Having this query I got wrong result.

I wanted to get id's from '2015-01-01' '20:00:00' to '2015-02-01' '20:00:00' time period.

How to get appropriate results without using timestamp data type?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
SELECT id,the_day,the_time FROM micro_climate WHERE

(the_day = '2015-01-01' AND the_time >= '20:00:00') -- First day's records
OR
(the_day BETWEEN '2015-01-02' AND '2015-01-31') -- Inbetween days
    OR
( the_day='2015-02-01' AND the_time <= '20:00:00'); -- last day's records
```

Alternatively, you can cast your values as timestamps. Note that the BETWEEN clause is inclusive, so if you have a value at exactly 20:00:00 you will get that...

```
SELECT id,the_day,the_time FROM micro_climate
WHERE (the_day || ' ' || the_time)::timestamp 
    BETWEEN ('2015-01-01' || ' 20:00:00')::timestamp 
    AND ('2015-02-01' || ' 20:00:00')::timestamp
```

EDIT

The following query might speed up the second query, especially if you add an index on the_day. It works by pre-extracting all possible records, then only doing the type conversion on those. You're probably better off with a timestamp, though...

```
WITH micro_climate_extract AS 
(SELECT * from micro_climate WHERE the_day BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-02-01')
SELECT id,the_day,the_time FROM micro_climate_extract
WHERE (the_day || ' ' || the_time)::timestamp 
    BETWEEN ('2015-01-01' || ' 20:00:00')::timestamp 
    AND ('2015-02-01' || ' 20:00:00')::timestamp
```

Comment: Sorry but first example is for 2 days interval, i wanted for 1 month. Second example worked well and took much time to finish the query . There're 10 millon rows. May be, I should set index in order to increase performance? If yes which index can help a lot in this situation ?

Comment: @ShohruhRaxmatov Index could help a lot, but using a timestamp datatype instead of the date+time kludge will solve all your problems.